# Sort Alrgorithm time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

```
void MySort(table T[0..n-1]: array of integers) 
{
   for m = 0 to n-2 do //will run n+1
   {
     j = m; // will run n times
     for k = m+1 to n-1 do /will run n^2 +n
     {
        if T[k] < T[j] then j = k; //will run n^2 times
     }
     swap(T[m], T[j]); //will run 3*n times
   }
}
```

I have to find the time complexity of this algorithm, and find the category it belongs.
So i calculate it will run 2n^2+6n+1 and it's category is O(n^2)
I would like to know if i am correct, and another question is is Ω also n^2 and Θ also n^2 ?

Comment: I almost said this is a bubble sort, but... it's not.  In fact, this doesn't sort.  Note the fact that `swap` only runs `n-2` times (not the claimed 3n times), and the theoretical minimum for a comparison sort like this is O(n*log(n))

Comment: ok about the swap i see the mistake but it does sort i tried it on a compiler

Comment: okay no matter what it does, the question is to find the complexity of this algorithm, so what is the complexity and how many times will it run at worst?

Comment: and the reason it does not work the way you wrote it is because in the two for you have given a < parameter comparison while it should be <= for example for for(int m=0; m<=T.length-2; m++)

Comment: I stand corrected, this does indeed sort! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bfc012a2251db8  Somehow.  O.o

Comment: what about the complexity now? can you help me there please?

Comment: Oh, I see, this is a selection sort.  (If I knew the answers, I would post an answer)  I'll review the big-O notations Ω and Θ so I can make an answer

Comment: please in your response be thorough i am completely new in time complexity and i feel i have not understood it correctly and none of the tutorials i have found seem to answer my questions

Comment: @MooingDuck I think this is much more like *Selection Sort*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definitions on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Big Omicron O - function is bounded above (by up to constant factor) asymptotically
Your analysis of O(n^2) is correct (though your anyalysis of swap is wrong)

Big Omega Ω - function is bounded below asymptotically
Your analysis of Ω(n^2) is correct (though your anyalysis of swap is wrong)

Big Theta Θ - is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically
As the Big Omnicron and Big Omega are the same, the big Theta is the same as those two: Θ(n^2)

---

As for *detailed* analysis of each part:
The outside-loop does run `n-1`, and there's one inner-loop and swap per iteration of that. Ergo, there is `n-1` swaps as well.

The inner-loop-body runs n-m times for each m, which is where the math gets complicated. The `T[k] < T[j]` gets executed `((n-1)-1)(n-2)/2 = (n^2)/2+2-2` times (I think).

The `j = k` is harder still, because now probability gets involved. I think it's the `sum of lg(m)` where `m` is the numbers `1 to n-1`.  After much math, I *think* that's `lg(n!)/0.60206`, and no, I have no idea where that constant came from or what it means.

---

You should know, your code is a [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), and the wikipedia page on selection sorts backs up my thoughts.

Comment: can you also analyse the T(n)? i thought it was 2n^2+6n+1 but i guess it is wrong, and how is T(n) or the analysis how many times the algorith will be run in the worst case(depending on the value of n), is called?

Comment: Not sure but it seems the outer loop is n-2 while the inner one n-3, thus more or less O(n^2)

Comment: (1) I've never heard of a T(n) and don't see it on the wikipedia page.  It looks like you simply multiplied (n-2) and (n-3), but if you're trying to do what I _think_ you're trying to do, the real math is far more complex.  Which is why we don't normally go deeper than big theta. (oh wait, I found it on the wiki page)

Comment: The wikipedia page merely uses `T(n)` as a poorly defined theoretical number of steps for an algorithm to complete.  However, calculating _actual_ T(n) is (as I said) hard.  I wouldn't bother.  If you really want to, you first have to define "what is a step"?  Normal definitions are "number of swaps" or "number of writes" or "number of comparisons", or (rarely) "number of seconds"

Comment: and by my calculations the j=k will run (n-2)^2 the vested for will run (n-2)^2 + n the swap will run 3*(n-2) the j=m will run (n-2) and the outside for will run (n-2)+1 if we put it together it is
(n-2)^2+(n-2)^2 + n + 3*(n-2) +(n-2) +(n-2) + 1=...= 2n^2 + 6n + 2 which is practically O(n^2), are my assumptions about each command correct?

Comment: @Kostas: No.  The outside-loop does run `n-1`, and there's one inner-loop and swap per iteration of that.  Ergo, there is `n-1` swaps as well.  The inner-loop-body runs `n-m` times for each `m`, which is where the math gets complicated.  The `T[k] < T[j]` gets executed `(n-2)(n-2)/2 = (n^2)/2+2-2` times (I think).  The `j = k` is harder still, because now _probability_ gets involved.  It should be...

Comment: [15 minutes of math and logarithm research later] `lg(n!)/0.60206`  (No, I haven't the faintest idea where that number comes from or why it's required.

Comment: well (n-2)+1 is n-1 so there we agree, and yes it gets really complicated, thank you for your help though i guess i will have to ask the professor if it is really necessary to know how many times each one runs

Comment: @Kostas: Professors will almost never ask you about `T(n)`, especially without clearly defining what `T(n)` is representing.  If you think that's what he asked, talk to him to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply proceed like the following:

[image]